# Turn Off YouTube Branding Links

Tags: youtube-api

I have an iOS app that shows YouTube videos.  I'm trying to remove the ability for the viewer to jump to the main YouTube site.  The YouTube link that appears at the top right part of the screen as well as the link that appears at the bottom right can be turned off by adding the following flags &modestbranding=1&showinfo=0.

The problem is, once you do this YouTube will add a YouTube watermark image at the bottom right of the video, if tapped it will take the viewer to the YouTube site.

I would like to just show the video with no YouTube active links. I don't mind the watermark or any other branding, I just don't want the link to be active.

Any thought?

Comment: This is not possible, it goes against YouTube's terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` to disable user interaction with the playing video.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but that would disable the video controls as well.

Comment: You can implement your own playback controls, YouTube's documentation can help: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls